# On the string class at member function and out_of_range exception handling

Tags: c++

Write in front:
My mother tongue is not English. I have some problems running the program. This is already explained in my headline. This function is to show whether the two output strings are alphabetical hexes; The order in which the letters of the two strings appear in the same number of letters can be arbitrary, but the two strings cannot be the same eg:slient and lisent are ectopic)
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
bool LetterChange(string s1,string s2);
int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;
    if (LetterChange(s1, s2) == true)
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not ok " << endl;
    return 0;
}
bool LetterChange(string s1, string s2)
{
    unsigned k = 0;
    if (s1.size() == s2.size())
    {
        if (s1.compare(s2) != 0)
        {
            unsigned i = 0;
            unsigned j = 0;
            while( i < s1.size())
            {
                for(unsigned j=0;j < s2.size();)
                {
                    if (s1.at(i) == s2.at(j) )
                    {
                        ++i;
                        ++k;
                    }
                    else
                        ++j;
                }
            }
            if (k == s1.size())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Although my words are awkward, thank you for your observations and answers.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you are trying to find whether the strings are anagrams?  If yes, a naive algorithm would be to sort the characters in both strings and compare the sorted results.  If they are equal, the strings are anagrams.

Comment: I suspect the reason `at` is throwing an exception is that you aren't ensuring `i` < `s1.size()` within the inner `for` loop. I suspect this might be due to the fact that you're creating two `j` variables (and only using one of them, which gets set to 0 on every `while` iteration). Also, your English is actually pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to check if in two words of the same length there are the same letters, but not in the same order? You can do it easier by checking if every letter from one word appears in the second one:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
bool LetterChange(string s1,string s2);
int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;
    if (LetterChange(s1, s2) == true)
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not ok " << endl;
    return 0;
}
bool LetterChange(string s1, string s2)
{
    //at the beginning check if they are the same of the size does not agree
    if(s1 == s2 or s1.size()!= s2.size()) return false;   
    else{
        //for every letter in s1, check if it appears in s2
        for(auto letter : s1){  
            //if some letter does not appear, we should return false 
            if(s2.find(letter)==string::npos) return false;
        }
        //if all letters from s1 appear in s2, return true
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
listen
sliten
ok

listen
listen
not ok

listeen
listen
not ok
```